# Good free guide for mod_security?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-security

I have looked at the official sites documentation, and it is a little tough to find starting points.

Is there a free comprehensive guide that is easy to understand for someone that has never dealt with mod_security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [ModSecurity for Apache User Guide](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/modsecurity-manual.html)? It's a little dated, but I am sure it has plenty of relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but the "ModSecurity 2.5" book is pretty good. Here's the Slashdot review: http://books.slashdot.org/story/10/01/13/1424213/ModSecurity-25?from=rss